# How can I visualize Git Flow branches?

Tags: git

I use the [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/img/2009/12/Screen-shot-2009-12-24-at-11.32.03.png) workflow. But I can't generate a good-looking log in tree graph. The size is too small and won't show all the branch relationships like in the Git Flow chart.

[image]

How can I create a graph like this for my Git repository?

This is [how Tower shows it](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/droplr.storage/files/acc_166785/FyjI?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSVQN3Z4K7MT5U2A&Expires=1389260497&Signature=vzxipK3jOY/TZprmRmc1qcNAL64=&response-content-disposition=inline;%20filename=FyjI.png).

Comment: Asking for tool recommendations is not encouraged. In essence, are you asking how to create a log that resembles the Git Flow graph? Do you need this via `git log` or a graphical tool? Have you seen [Visualizing branch topology in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838873/visualizing-branch-topology-in-git)?

Comment: The utility I use is `tig`. But that’s just a terminal utility that shows branches; it won’t paint any fancy images (`graphviz` or other).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have not specified whether you are looking for a command line tool or not, but if so, I find that something like this gives you a good appreciation of the branch structure

```
git log --all --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

And of course you can create an alias for this with git config, eg

```
git config --global alias.lg "log --all --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit"
```

Comment: In Windows, replace ```'``` for ```"```

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you to use [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) to get such images.
It is a Git GUI client for Windows, Mac and Linux.
In it you have a nice visuals like the Commit History.

[image: GitKraken]

There are more Git GUIs, such as:

• [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com), available for free for Windows and MacOS.

• [Tower](https://www.git-tower.com/mac)

[Here's a list of them from Git's official website](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis/) and [a list of them from Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Git_GUIs) that may be of help.

Answer (score 5):

If your code is in a public github repo, you might want to look at http://beta.gitflowchart.com. For Atlassian Stash, there is [a plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.collabsoft.plugins.stash.gfc) that does this too (not free).

Disclosure: I wrote the underlying library for both tools.

Comment: I wanted to give http://beta.gitflowchart.com/ a try, but it asking for too many permissions for me to be comfortable with: "This application will be able to read and write all public repository data. This includes the following:". Why is it requesting write access to everything?

Comment: @AdamRalph: yes, that is unfortunate. If you request access to a users data, you pass in a scope. This is defined here: https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes
I'm not sure what the correct way of requesting only read access to your public repos would be. Please take my word that we will only read your data and not change anything.

Comment: If the repos are public anyway, why do you need to specify anything for them? You already have access, no?

Comment: Yes, that sounds plausible. I have to look into that again. Actually a long time since we put our that beta. I'm not actively working on it.

Comment: @AdamRalph I've fixed that. The site now requires only to read your public data. Thanks for alerting me, this scope was very inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I am happy with [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).

- It's free and available for Win and MacOS.
- It shows branches in actually understandable graph.
- It renders branches using consistent coloring (one branch ~ one color)

[image]